# How to set default to empty string in docopt

Tags: python, docopt

I have a docopt Usage string that has something like:

```
"""
Usage
...
    -d --data=<data>    Input data [default: ??]
...
"""
```

How to set the default value to emtpy string?

`''` sets it to string `"''"` and
`[default: ]` raises a `KeyError '--data'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported at this point. I created an issue: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/118

**Edit:** I was pointed out that this is actually possible with `[default: ]`. But this is a bit awkward. I still recommend not using `[default: ...]` in this case and just describe the default using English, and handle the conversion from `None` to empty string internally.